# plugin for generating Bézier or Spline from google.maps.Polyline

Tags: google-maps-api-3, spline

I need to draw lines on google map.
Currently I am using google.maps.Polyline for this purpose and everything worked fine

But the line just doesn't look so nice.
I would like to substitute is with Bezier or Spline.

Has anyone done anything like this or have seen any decent plugin or library? The only thing I found is [this link](http://johan.karlsteen.com/2011/07/30/improving-google-maps-polygons-with-b-splines/).

With polygons:
[image]

with splines:
[image]

This is an old question, but so for people who ask me whether I have found anything, the answer is "no".